# C# Datagridview doesn't show records with single apostrophe

Tags: c#, sql

.NET client application DataGridView doesn't show records that have single apostrophe
while the .NET website grid shows the records correctly

Example records in SQL:

Record 1: Two 19' wheels
Record 2: Two 19'' wheels

Notes:
* Record 1 uses a single apostrophe, while Record 2 uses double apostrophe

- The .NET client application datagridview would show the Record 2 but not Record 1 (record 1 totally is invisible)
- The .NET client application uses OleDBAdapter to read the data from a .mdb temporary file (not sure if this impacts) but initially the data comes from a SQL Server
- I tried doing a 'REPLACE' in the query but it just throws and error that the Query is not valid although when I try to do it in SQL Management Studio query it works fine.
- The .NET website created the records and it displays both records properly

Appreciate the insights in advance!

Comment: Here's the syntax for MS Access replace https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/replace.php. What error do you actually get? it would really help if you posted code and errors otherwise we're just guessing

Comment: This is likely to be an error with selecting the data from the database and nothing to do with the datagrid.

Comment: Yup apparently it's data issue, already figured out. and I upgraded to the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 and the replace function was useable. thanks for the reply.